# Highlight tab in menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a menu which is a ul

```
Home | Calendar | Settings
```

I want to highlight (via a css class) the selected tab in the menu.

Some links (Home and Calendar) also have subselections

```
Home | *Calendar* | Settings 
------------------------- 
Add event | Edit event
```

Ofcourse when edit event is selected, Calendar should still be highlighted.

how can I best approach this using rails and css?

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The simplest way would be to check which controller is being used. I made up controller names, so of course you would replace 'home', 'calendar', and 'settings' with the correct names.

```
<ul>
  <li class="<%= "highlighted" if params[:controller] == "home" %>">Home</li>
  <li class="<%= "highlighted" if params[:controller] == "calendar" %>">Calendar</li>
  <li class="<%= "highlighted" if params[:controller] == "settings" %>">Settings</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 19):

In your helper file:

```
def is_active?(page_name)
  "active" if params[:action] == page_name
end
```

In the template file:

```
link_to 'Home', '/', :class => is_active?("index")
link_to 'About', '/about', :class => is_active?("about")
link_to 'contact', '/contact', :class => is_active?("contact")
```

I found this on: http://juliocapote.com/post/52081481/highlight-link-based-on-current-page-in-rails

Answer (score 5):

I settled on this solution which I like a lot:

In the helper

```
def active_if(options)
  if params.merge(options) == params
    'nav-active'
  end
end
```

And in the view define what makes the route unique:

```
<%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: active_if(action: 'home') %>
<%= link_to 'Aricles', articles_path, class: active_if(controller: 'articles') %>
```

Comment: This is the best and most flexible solution proposed here as it allows to match on anything in `params`. You get my +1.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and end up creating helper. 
basicly it replace the link_to url helper so it wrap the link with li and add class "menu_selected" if the current controller matches the link controller

usage sample

```
<%= menu_link_to "Home", home_path %>
```

```
def menu_link_to(*args, &block)
  url = args[1]
  mapping =  ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path(url)   

  class_property = "menu_selected" if mapping[:controller] == controller.controller_path
  content_tag :li, :class => class_property do
    link_to *args, &block
  end
end
```

Comment: I added `if (args[1].is_a?(Hash)) url = url_for(args[1])` to recognize the old style `:controller/:action` format.

Answer (score 1):

Update to @ahmy's answer for Rails 3.2:

```
def menu_list_item(*args, &block)
  url = args[1]
  mapping =  Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(url)   

  li_class = 'active' if mapping[:controller] == controller.controller_path
  content_tag :li, :class => li_class do
    link_to *args, &block
  end
end
```

i.e. `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` instead of `ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize_path`.