# Rails Highlight current menu nave in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I have this in my application.html.erb file:

```
<div class="mainMenu">
<%= link_to 'Movies', dvds_path %>  
<%= link_to 'Books', books_path %>  
<%= link_to 'Albums', cds_path %> 
<%= link_to 'Games', games_path %> 
</div>
```

I would like to put a class of "highlight" on the menus if we are on each of the pages, so for example, in the Movies page, if we are in dvds_path then it would be:

```
<%= link_to 'Movies', dvds_path, :class => 'highlight' %>
```

But can't seem to figure it out, none of these methods worked for me:

[using the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829727/highlight-tab-in-menu)

[using a helper](http://juliocapote.com/post/52081481/highlight-link-based-on-current-page-in-rails)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
link_to_unless_current(name, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Creates a link tag of the given name using a URL created by the set of options unless the current request URI is the same as the links, in which case only the name is returned (or the given block is yielded, if one exists). You can give link_to_unless_current a block which will specialize the default behavior (e.g., show a “Start Here” link rather than the link’s text).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current

So you could style your 'links' as unselected in your nav bar, and have a 'selected' style when the link is not present..

```
li { color:#fff; } /* selected */
li a { color:#333; }
li a:hover { color:#999; }

<ul id="navbar">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li><a href="/controller/about">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this works great but I can't put an image in the unselected (current) link because there is no mechanism to put the class with highlight on it since it's not a link at all. I tried setting the background image to none for the ones that are links but that didn't work. Could I give the current page (the one that is no longer a link) a class? If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that if you put it in a do block, you can assign an alternate content value if the link is current..

The implicit block given to link_to_unless_current is evaluated if the current action is the action given. So, if we had a comments page and wanted to render a “Go Back” link instead of a link to the comments page, we could do something like this…

```
<%=
  link_to_unless_current("Comment", { :controller => "comments", :action => "new" }) do
    image_tag src=>"/image.jpg"
  end
%>
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure it out from the example on the link you sent, thanks again.