# ruby on rails get page name from route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, routes

I have a users controller which is used for users profile

then i routed from

```
/users/{username}
```

to

```
/{username}
```

but now if i want to add pages like

- About Us
- Help
- Contact Us
- ToS
- Privacy
- etc...

i face a problem where i cant access which page i am at via the `params[]` code

my route looks like

```
  match '/home' => 'home#index'

  #change /users/{username} to /{username}
  match '/:username' => 'users#show'
```

i need to know which page i am for my navigation menu so i can add an active class to highlight the page

is there any way i can do this?

Comment: You may be able to use current_page?

Comment: i get an error` undefined local variable or method `current_page'`

Comment: The method is `current_page?` - the question mark is part of the method name :) http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by checking which controller i am using

`params[:controller]` in the if conditional

Answer (score 0):

```
for /fxuser route
controller.action_name     # => show
controller.controller_name # => users

for /home route
controller.action_name     # => index
controller.controller_name # => home
```

Comment: I dont really get this... am i supposed to change `/fxuser` to something like `'/:username'` also what do i change below the `for` line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `params[:controller]` although I'm not sure if thats the best way to do it.

Also your questions sounds like a duplicate of [Highlight tab in menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829727/highlight-tab-in-menu)

Comment: I only have problem highlighting a tab when i create new pages since i cant use the `params[]` variable to get on which page i am

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'create new pages'!

Comment: i want to add an About page for my website... how do i detect that i am on the `/about` page so i can highlight the About item in my menu?

Comment: You add a new controller and route the '/about' url to it. 
`get '/about' => 'about#index'`
In your application.html.erb you can use params[:controller] to set a CSS class on the tab you want to highlight. A better way would be to use the current_page? method as @ramblex mentions